# Search for magic squares

Tags: python, math

I am trying to create a program that searches for magic squares.

```
class square:
    def __init__(self, n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9):
        self.row1 = n1+n2+n3
        self.row2 = n4+n5+n6
        self.row3 = n7+n8+n9
        self.col1 = n1+n4+n7
        self.col2 = n2+n5+n8
        self.col3 = n3+n6+n9
        self.diag1 = n1+n5+n9
        self.diag2 = n3+n5+n7
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self.n3 = n3
        self.n4 = n4
        self.n5 = n5
        self.n6 = n6
        self.n7 = n7
        self.n8 = n8
        self.n9 = n9

    def checkMagic(self):
        if (self.row1==self.row2==self.row3==self.col1==self.col2==self.col3==self.diag1==self.diag2):
            print("magic square found")
            print(str(self.n1) + " " + str(self.n2) + " " + str(self.n3))
            print(str(self.n4) + " " + str(self.n5) + " " + str(self.n6))
            print(str(self.n7) + " " + str(self.n8) + " " + str(self.n9))
```

So far this will create a square and check if it is magic. I would like to iterate through and create/check all possible magic squares for numbers under some integer k. For example, if I set it at k = 10, it should find this square:

square(2,7,6,9,5,1,4,3,8)

Here is some more information on magic squares for anyone who would like to know more:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html

Comment: This seems mostly a mathematics problem. Maybe look up the algorithms for magic squares and think about which one you want to implement? Or you could start with a 'brute force' approach - try every possible square and check if it is magic or not - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes I have currently done it for brute force but it is very slow. I'd like to use lumpy later but can't find algorithms for just searching rather than constructing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more general function to check whether a square represented as a list of numbers is magic:

```
def is_magic_square(cells):
    width = int(len(cells) ** .5)

    # Start with 1st diagonal total
    total = sum(cells[::width+1])
    # Check 2nd diagonal
    if sum(cells[width-1:len(cells)-1:width-1]) != total:
        return False

    # Check row totals
    for i in range(0, len(cells)-1, width):
        if sum(cells[i:i+width]) != total:
            return False

    # Check column totals
    for i in range(width):
        if sum(cells[i::width]) != total:
            return False

    return True
```

You can then check all of the squares with a given width like this.

```
def find_magic_squares(width):
    for sequence in itertools.permutations(range(1, width*width+1)):
        if is_magic_square(sequence):
            print("Found magic square:", sequence)
```

This is clearly still a brute force approach and becomes very slow with width greater than 3. But may be a helpful way to start.

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm for generating Magic Squares of 9 cells totaling `c`**

**Edit** taking into consideration the ***distinct numbers*** feature, commented by @Stuart.

These will be the group of equations, and matrix describing it:

[image]
[image]

Now, solving using [Gaussian elimination](https://matrixcalc.org/en/slu.html#solve-using-Gaussian-elimination%28%7B%7B1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,c%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,c%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,c%7D,%7B1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,c%7D,%7B0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,c%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,c%7D,%7B1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,c%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,c%7D%7D%29), the equations will finally reduce to:

```
x1=2*c/3-x9
x2=2*c/3-x8
x3=(-c)/3+x8+x9
x4=(-2*c)/3+x8+2*x9
x5=c/3
x6=4*c/3-x8-2*x9
x7=c-x8-x9
x8=x8
x9=x9
```

now considering that all cells must be `integers greater than 0`, you will only need to try the substitution of `x8` and `x9` cells, starting from `1` to `c`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


total = 18


def main():
  custom_print(calc_magic_2d_list(total))


def calc_magic_2d_list(tot):

  def check_magic(arr):
    if not len(arr) == 9:
      return False
    for no in arr:
      if no <= 0 or not (no - int(no)) == 0:
        return False
    return True

  x5 = tot / 3
  if x5 > 0 and (x5 - int(x5)) == 0:
    pass
  else:
    raise Exception('no magic boxes of 9 cells for total of {}'.format(str(tot)))

  magic_boxes = set()
  for y9 in range(tot):
    for y8 in range(tot):
      magic_box = []
      magic_box.append(2*tot/3 - y9)
      magic_box.append(2*tot/3 - y8)
      magic_box.append((-tot)/3 + y8 + y9)
      magic_box.append((-2*tot)/3 + y8 + 2*y9)
      magic_box.append(tot/3)
      magic_box.append(4*tot/3 - y8 - 2*y9)
      magic_box.append(tot - y8 - y9)
      magic_box.append(y8)
      magic_box.append(y9)
      magic_box = OrderedDict.fromkeys(magic_box)

      if check_magic(magic_box):
        magic_box = [int(x) for x in magic_box]
        magic_boxes.add(tuple(magic_box[:]))

  return magic_boxes


def custom_print(lst_of_magic):
  for magic in lst_of_magic:
    print(magic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

And, this is the output, when `c = 18`:

```
(3, 10, 5, 8, 6, 4, 7, 2, 9)
(9, 2, 7, 4, 6, 8, 5, 10, 3)
(9, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 11, 3)
(3, 11, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8, 1, 9)
(5, 3, 10, 11, 6, 1, 2, 9, 7)
(7, 9, 2, 1, 6, 11, 10, 3, 5)
(7, 1, 10, 9, 6, 3, 2, 11, 5)
(5, 11, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 1, 7)
(3, 8, 7, 10, 6, 2, 5, 4, 9)
(8, 1, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 11, 4)
(4, 5, 9, 11, 6, 1, 3, 7, 8)
(2, 11, 5, 9, 6, 3, 7, 1, 10)
(5, 10, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2, 7)
(2, 9, 7, 11, 6, 1, 5, 3, 10)
(5, 4, 9, 10, 6, 2, 3, 8, 7)
(9, 5, 4, 1, 6, 11, 8, 7, 3)
(9, 4, 5, 2, 6, 10, 7, 8, 3)
(10, 3, 5, 1, 6, 11, 7, 9, 2)
(3, 7, 8, 11, 6, 1, 4, 5, 9)
(7, 2, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 10, 5)
(8, 7, 3, 1, 6, 11, 9, 5, 4)
(7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 10, 9, 4, 5)
(10, 1, 7, 3, 6, 9, 5, 11, 2)
(4, 11, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 8)
```

Comment: The numbers should be distinct integers - i.e. squares with numbers repeated have to be removed.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and yes they should be distinct integers but this is fine for right now! Thank you!

Comment: @PatrickMaynard check the answer, I've updated it to allow only distinct numbers.

Comment: The 3 boxes you found for `total=18` are not valid and when `total=15` it returns `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`. Check the definitions... "a magic square is a n x n square grid ... filled with distinct positive integers in the range 1,2,...n^2"

Comment: @Stuart I've just noted they are not ordered, I'm solving it and reupdating.

Comment: @Stuart I used `set` to eliminate repetition, but slipped the downside that `sets` are **not ordered**. Now, I'm using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

Comment: The magic box is not supposed to be ordered. You could check if is valid with something like `set(magic_box) == set(range(1, 10))`.

Comment: @Stuart what do u mean?, oc it should be ordered. It's in the very core of magic square definition.

Comment: @Stuart Order here means that each **cell must sustain its position in the resulting array**; i.e it wouldn't satisfy the checks if `cell1` is replaced by `cell5` for example.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it is ordered. I confused ordered and sorted. It might be easier to check `len(set(arr)) == 9` instead of converting to an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Stuart in addition to that, `OrderedDict` is better in the sense that it **preserves the order of the input elements**.

Comment: wow this was very helpful thanks for going above and beyond on this one. In case anyone's curious I'm currently working on try to lower the search space and make the brute force approach more efficient.